# How to extract the C# code from the razor files(CsHtml)?

Tags: c#, razor, roslyn

I am building a Console app that can scan MVC apps and simple asp.Net classes(i.e .cs file).
    I have used roslyn parser for the simple C# code and it is working fine :).
    Now i want to scan the razor files but it is not getting scanned by the roslyn compiler as it is with the C#. Leme give you an example....this is my Razor file..

```
@using System.Text;
@using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
@using System.Configuration;
@using System.Data;
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
    ViewBag.Title = "throwEx";
}
<h2>throwEx</h2>
<h3>
    @{
        string name = "";
        string country = "";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", name));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Country", country));
        int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(constr, CommandType.Text, "query", parameters.ToArray()));
    }
</h3>
```

Here i want to scan only the C# code.. how to extract only  @{*this Part only :)}.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What code have you tried for 'scanning' ? Are you wanting the code to recourse through a directory and match on file types , use the view as an input argument ....?

Comment: No i am not getting any specific error, the thing is my App will scan web apps and detect any violations like i want developers to not to use Inline Queries instead they should use Stored procedure.. so in this case if they have written this code it should create a volation :) . and it working fine in the normal .cs pages but here it is not detecting this part of snippet as a c# it is taking it as simple text document :(.... i just want to extract this C# code and pass it as a Cs Doc to the parser :) but how? :(

Comment: and thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: You shouldn't have SQL queries of any kind in cshtml files.  Those belong in controllers.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor/Parser may be helpful.

Comment: Well, for the general case, you need a Razor parser. As far as I'm aware, Roslyn doesn't support Razor, so you'll need to run the code through the Razor parser, then extract all the C# code, and finally use that C# code in Roslyn in a meaningful way :)

Comment: Thanx evryone For the support.@slaks yeah you are right actually thats just for the sake of an example... I wont b using any business logic inside a view :) thanks for the link :)

Comment: @luaan-thanks for the info, actually i am new to this kind. I will start googling it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a console app that can take in arguments (file names / other) and use a streamreader. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 0)
            {
                string line = null;
                string targetStart = "@{";
                string targetEnd = "}";
                string fileName = args[0];

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line.Contains(targetStart))
                    {
                        while (reader.ReadLine() != targetEnd)
                        {
                            var readLine = reader.ReadLine();
                            if (readLine != null) Console.WriteLine(readLine.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

** I tested this on .cshtml and it worked